# For some number of matrices, when are there a finite number of distinct finite products?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose you have a set of some number of square matrices $\{A_i\}$ and generate the set of all finite products of elements of this set. When is this set finite?

<s>To rephrase the question, perhaps more formally:</s>

> Consider a set $S$ of $n \times n$ matrices. When does $S$ have finite span?

It is easy to see that the determinants of every matrix must be $-1, 0$ or $1$. If there was a matrix which had some other determinant, then $\det(A^2)=\det(A)\det(A) != \det(A)$, and in fact the matrices $A^k$ all have different determinants so they form an infinite set.

Considering a set of just two $2$ x $2$ matrices $\{A,B\}$, we must have $A$ and $B$ either be rotations or map to a line. Ignoring the former case (where we have $\det(A), \det(B) \not= 0$), the set will be finite when $A$ and $B$ both rotate by a rational multiple of $\pi$, and equally will be infinite when one or both matrices rotate by irrational multiples of $\pi$. This also holds for more than just two basis matrices.

Now consider the $0-$determinant case for two $2 \times 2$ matrices. If both matrices have $0$ determinant, then the resultant set is trivially finite. If only one matrix has $0$ determinant, then the set will be infinite unless the $0$ determinant matrix preserves the length of vectors in the space it maps to (or we would have $A^k$ distinct for all $k$), and the other rotates by $\frac{n\pi}{2}$ for some integer $n$ (or we would have $(AB)^k$ distinct for all $k$).

The real problem arises in the case of larger square matrices. For any one matrix $A$, we know that for a finite span under matrix multiplication, we must have $A^k=A$ for some $k$, which is equivalent to rotating by a rational multiple of $\pi$. But, if we have two matrices $A$ and $B$ like this, I'm not convinced that we even have $(AB)^k$ all distinct, nevermind more arbitrary combinations.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The rephrasing is asking  a completely different question.

Comment: @copper.hat I was thinking of it as the matrices being elements of their own vector space, and considering the span under product. It doesn't seem to helpful though - I've struck it out.